# KeepassX swaps y and z

Tags: 11.10, keyboard-layout, keepass

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity and want to use KeepassX but the keyboard layout seems to be wrong in this application only. The layout works fine for all other applications. I am using a German keyboard layout. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this command to the startup applications:

```
setxkbmap de
```

Another option to add the command to the `.profile` script, as [described here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1900903)

Comment: Weeeeeh! This bug has been driving me mad for so long. Auto-type was broken and useless. But this fixed it for me.